# Configuring envoy to skip mTLS on a specific http route

Tags: envoyproxy

I am using envoy has an edge proxy.
Basically I want mTLS downstream on all http paths except for one.
I have the following config:
Notice how I set `require_client_certificate: false` in the first route

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /dev/stdout
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 127.0.0.1
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 443
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/s1/request/get"
                  headers:
                  - name: ":method"
                    exact_match: "GET"
                route:
                  host_rewrite_literal: service1
                  cluster: internal_service1
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          require_client_certificate: false
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              certificate_chain: 
                filename: /etc/ssl/listener/cert.pem
              private_key: 
                filename: /etc/ssl/listener/key.pem
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca:
                filename: /etc/ssl/cluster/cabundle.pem
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/s1/request/post"
                  headers:
                  - name: ":method"
                    exact_match: "POST"
                route:
                  host_rewrite_literal: service1
                  cluster: internal_service1
                 
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          require_client_certificate: true
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              certificate_chain: 
                filename: /etc/ssl/listener/cert.pem
              private_key: 
                filename: /etc/ssl/listener/key.pem
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca:
                filename: /etc/ssl/cluster/cabundle.pem

  clusters:
  - name: internal_service1
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: internal_service1
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: service1
                port_value: 443
    tls_context:
      allow_renegotiation: true
      common_tls_context:
        tls_certificates:
          certificate_chain: 
            filename: /etc/ssl/listener/cert.pem
          private_key: 
            filename: /etc/ssl/listener/key.pem
        validation_context:
          trusted_ca:
            filename: /etc/ssl/cluster/cabundle.pem
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
        sni: service1
```

So, when I do a

```
curl -k  --location  --cacert cabundle.pem --request GET 'http://localhost:443/s1/request/get'
```

I expect the request to go through and get a 200 response

Whereas, I if I hit `/s1/request/post`, then I expect mTLS to take place so I should be providing a certificate and a key.

However, when I start the envoy, I get the following error

```
[2020-10-28 05:42:40.674][1][debug][init] [source/common/init/watcher_impl.cc:27] init manager Server destroyed
error adding listener '0.0.0.0:443': multiple filter chains with the same matching rules are defined
make: *** [run-local] Error 1
```

Is this the correct way to do the stuff I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
Referring to https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/route/route_components.proto#envoy-api-msg-route-routematch-tlscontextmatchoptions

The only caveat is that this has to be repeat for each route, setting the values appropriately for each route.

Comment: Hi @kosta, did you ever get this to work?  Would you be able to post your envoy config please?

Answer (score 0):

@kosta you need to specify a new field [`filter_chain_match`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/listener/listener_components.proto#envoy-api-msg-listener-filterchainmatch) on your TLS listener.  Basically, right now your two listeners are supposed to match ALL incoming connections, and so envoy doesn't know which one to use for any given connection.

If you add the field below to your second listener, it will only match on TLS connections, which will allow Envoy to start.

```
filter_chain_match:
  transport_protocol: tls
```

I modified your second listener as shown below, and envoy started up fine.

```
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/s1/request/post"
                  headers:
                  - name: ":method"
                    exact_match: "POST"
                route:
                  host_rewrite_literal: service1
                  cluster: internal_service1
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      filter_chain_match:
        transport_protocol: "tls"
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          require_client_certificate: true
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              certificate_chain: 
                filename: /etc/ssl/listener/cert.pem
              private_key: 
                filename: /etc/ssl/listener/key.pem
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca:
                filename: /etc/ssl/cluster/cabundle.pem
```

Comment: The problem is I want the second filter to have `mTLS` while the first one to have simply `TLS`. If I do what you suggested, then all TLS requests are routed to the second filter.

Comment: Ahh, i'm sorry.  I misunderstood the initial question.  I don't _think_ what you want to do is possible.  The HTTP connection manager and HTTP router happen after the TLS connection has been established. So there would be no way to determine what HTTP route the request is going to until after the TLS handshake is finished, which means you can't have different certificate rules.    

I believe you'd need the route without mTLS to be on a different virtual host or port to make this happen.